# What does the "optional" keyword mean in a function declaration?

Tags: swift

What does `optional func myFunction() { .. }` mean in the Apple API docs; for example this entry for [UICollectionViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:) :

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Comment: Those methods are **not** part of the `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol. That code is an example from the section of [*The Swift Programming Language*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_402) which explains exactly what the `optional` keyword means.

Comment: Oops, sorry, wrong paste buffer, fixing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that classes adopting this protocol are not *required* to implement those methods in order to be conformant. Although not implementing any of these methods will not make for a good data source.